# restric view row by the URL in block

Tags: views, blocks

I have a view block disply that contains a list of nodes.
i want to restrict Nid's by my url in one field in node.(Similarly, system block visibility)
for example i have a field with name `field_visibility` and save node by fill that `gallery`

so, my list in block is:

> view-row-1 => [nid]-1 => field_visibility ='gallery'
>  view-row-2 =>
>   [nid]-2 => field_visibility ='contact'
>  view-row-3 => [nid]-3 =>
>   field_visibility ='blog'
>  .
>  .
>  .

so in page **www.example.com/gallery**, in block should be

```
1. [nid]-2
2. [nid]-3
```

and in page **www.example.com/contact**, in block should be

```
1. [nid]-1
2. [nid]-3
```

Comment: Have you tried to play a bit with contextual filters? Can I assume you tried to set contextual filter to "content: field visibility" and it somehow failed?

Comment: sorry, i use drupal 6-x and tried arguments but whit out success

Comment: Add both that informations to your question, then :) And I'm afraid I'm not able to help with 6, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `field_visibility`

try this if using Views 3

- Click on the "advanced" tab.
- Click on add under "contextual filters".
- Choose Content:nid.
- Under "when the filter variable is not available, choose "provide default value".
- From the drop down menu select "content id from url".
- Scroll all the way down to the bottom of the window and click on the "More" link.
- Click "Exclude"

Comment: sorry, i use drupal 6-x and not see this options

Comment: then use arguments filter